# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted(the total beginner in Django)

Tags: django

Don't judge me strictly. I'm the total beginner in Django. Here is my problem: I have a form with registration. When I push button 'Submit', here is the CSRF error. I tried to debug it, but I can't understand why the condition `if request.method == 'POST'` is not true?
here is my view method:

```
def Logging(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Login_Form(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('thanks.html')
    else:
        form = Login_Form()

    return render_to_response('login.html', {'form':form})
```

and my form:

```
<form method = "post">
    <table>
    {{form.as_table}}
    <input type = "submit" value="Login">
      </table>
</form>
```

and urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^login/', views.Logging),
    url(r'^thanks/', 'thanks.html')
)
```

Comment: Not judging you for being a newbie, but for failing to search to find any of the many questions that have been asked in the past; and for failing to read the very clear error message which tells you exactly what you are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add {% csrf_token %} inside form tag

```
<form method = "post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{form.as_table}}
    <input type = "submit" value="Login">
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: in your view :  return render_to_response('login.html', {'form':form})

Comment: and add import : **from django.shortcuts import render**

Comment: can i do with render_to_response?

Comment: this may work with it like this : `return render_to_response('login.html',
                          {'form':form},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

Comment: It works. Can you explain this line? context_instance=RequestContext(request)